# Qt Custom Widget Internal Boundary

Tags: qt

I've written a custom widget in Qt that subclasses and does custom painting, however it's a non-rectangular object (has a polygon top area), and it's working fine, however when adding layouts they 'break' into the top area as it's getting the wrong boundary area. Is there anyway I can specify within the custom widget what the boundary area is for child widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `QLayout::setContentsMargins` on the widget's layout.

If you want a boundary that's not rectangular, you can use a grid layout filled with fixed-size rectangular fillers. The fillers can be derived from the polygon using [scanline conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043448/1329652) -- just merge a number of scanlines into a taller bounding rectangle and use it for fillers.

Comment: I'm doing something similar at the moment, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to.

Comment: Well, you want to set the boundary, and voila, here is exactly how you'd set such a rectangular boundary. If you want a boundary that's not rectangular, you can use a grid layout filled with fixed-size rectangular fillers. The fillers can be derived from the polygon using [scanline conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11043448/1329652) -- just merge a number of scanlines into a taller bounding rectangle and use it for filler.

Comment: Ah hah, I misread the documentation and this is actually what I needed!