# Getting the pixels index covered by qpen while using qpainter on qimage

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qpainter, qimage

I am using qt for developing a simple drawing application.

I have a qImage and filled it as trasparent.

`QImage *m_markerImg = new QImage(400,320, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
m_markerImg -> fill( Qt::transparent );`

I have created a custom graphics scene by inheriting it from qgraphicsscene & drawing a line on this image in the mousemove event of graphics scene as:

`QPointF plotPoint = mouseEvent->scenePos();
m_painter.drawLine(m_initPoint,plotPoint);
m_initPoint=plotPoint;`

where m_initPoint is being assigned in mouse press event. Everything is working fine and i am able to draw lines over this image. Now i want to store the pixels covered by this line at runtime i.e. during line draw. 
Although i can store the points on which i am drawing i.e. m_initPoint & plotPoint but in case of penwidth is set to more than 1 , then i will get only a single line pixel while i need whole of the pixels covered by the width of this line.

How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Convert the line to a path,
2. Stroke the path using [`QPainterPathStroker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpathstroker.html) (see also [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-pathstroke-example.html)),
3. Get the stroked path as a polygon,
4. Scan (iterate) the pixels of the polygon - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11037252/1329652) for a complete example.

Comment: Sorry Kuba Ober, but i don't know how to stroke the line. Can you please provide some more info about it?

Comment: @ShubhamSaini I've linked relevant documentation/examples.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem, i'll be trying your solution. For now i've solved it by iterating the nearby pixels in vicinity. i.e. i am running loops on the pixels in the vicinity, checking their color and if they have the same color as i applied on them, i am appending them into QList<QPoint>. It is solving my problem.