# python: turn polygon into mask array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon which I want to turn into a mask array, such that all points that fall inside/outside the polygon are True/False. I thought I found the perfect solution ([SciPy Create 2D Polygon Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654289/scipy-create-2d-polygon-mask)), but for some reason this doesn't work!

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

nx, ny = 10, 10

poly = np.array([(1, 1), (6, 2), (9, 9), (3, 7)])

img = Image.new("L", [nx, ny], 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(poly, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)

print(mask)
# [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

---

Broader context:
I'm working with features of arbitrary shape on a rectangular grid. I have the indices of all boundary points on the grid, and I want the indices of a convex hull around this feature. `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull(boundary_points)` gives me the edge points of the convex hull, and it is this hull polygon that I now want to turn into a mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`poly` has to be a list of tuples or a flattened list. For some reason numpy arrays are handled badly. You can convert a polygon in a numpy array with `poly.ravel().tolist()` or with `list(map(tuple, poly))`.

Comment: my polygons numbers are in float type what should i do ?